# What should our site/domain name be?

Tags: discussion, 7-essential, names

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Write an Elevator Pitch / Tagline](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

### Note:

We are closing this domain naming thread. It is asking the *entirely* wrong question. See this blog post for details: [Domain Names: Wrong Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)

We're going to keep the name cstheory.stackexchange.com. But we WILL be setting up redirects from the more "popular" domains names. (e.g. seasonedadvice.com to cooking.stackexchange.com, basicallymoney.com to money.stackexchange.com, and others as we go through the list).

New question: "**Write and Elevator Pitch / Tagline!**"

[**Click here to contribute ideas and vote.**](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/463/write-an-elevator-pitch-tagline)

*[original message text below]*

---

**Update**: this post is now closed. CSTheory.org it is..

I'll start the ball rolling with the canonical question from 'The 7 essential meta questions'.

Please post each idea as an answer, and if you know, indicate whether it's taken or not. Based on past experience with other SE sites, a domain name that's parked but not taken is admissible.

**Note that you can vote more than once!**

Comment: Is there a way for people to change votes? In the beginning when there were very few good suggestions, I voted for one that was the best among those. Now that better ones have appeared, I would like to cancel my vote for that one.

Comment: You can always downvote the one you want to cancel and vote for the one you like

Comment: one possibility (if you have enough rep) is to trivially edit the answer and then change the vote. not ideal, but this is how it appears to work.

Comment: ok, that works.. Just tried it.

Comment: If you voted by clicking an up-arrow, just click it again to cancel your vote (if you click down-arrow you will change your vote from "yes" to "no" rather than to "no vote").

Comment: @Andrej Bauer: The catch is that you cannot cancel a vote unless the answer has been edited since you voted.  I guess that this is different from MathOverflow, which uses an older version of the StackExchange software.

Comment: Is the name with the highest votes going to be selected, or will we get down to a few finalists and then vote after some discussion?

Comment: I suspect we'd go with the highest voted name in this case, since the difference is quite large. If that changes, then maybe a runoff ?

Comment: Yep, the difference between CStheory.org and everything else is huge. Even if you flip all the *negative* votes for infinitestack and theoryoverflow to be positive votes, the count still doesn't beat cstheory.org. Let me recommend that everyone who dislikes cstheory.org to get your friends to (a) start participating on the site, and (b) vote for something else! (No duplicate IDs, please!)

Comment: @Surseh, @Ryan: Your comments assume that everyone voted among the top three.  I don't think the distribution is skewed enough -- say in some severe power law -- to assume that a runoff would produce the same outcome.

Comment: So.. voting has ended. If we're not having a runoff, it seems we have a new name!

Comment: yep. I think the plan is to inform Robert Cartaino about this.

Comment: This is great.  We should turn our attention to the logo, design, etc. now.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

## CSTheory.org

Extremely official and informative.
(A bit better grammatically than TheoryCS.org, I think; but both are good).

Comment: I like this one.  Short and to the point, easy to remember, and specific to our endeavor.

Comment: The only possible "problem" with this name is that it's too literal.

Comment: .com available, see http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-site-domain-name-be/163#163

Comment: It's a bit of a boring name! :)

Comment: Imagine the following exchange over coffee: "I posted my question on CSTheory and had a lot of interest!" and in (albeit possibly slightly slow but still validly confused) response, "Where did you post it?"

Comment: If we go this route, the _name_ of the site will probably be “CSTheory-dot-org” because “CSTheory” does not serve well as a name.  Is this really what we want?

Comment: Saying "I asked on sea-es-theory" is actually batter than what seems to be the norm for MathOverflow, which is "I asked on em-oh". I suspect we'll end up using the abbreviation CST for informal references to CSTheory.org (which seems to be the best choice so far).

Comment: I like CSTheory, but I'd prefer something more imaginative like "InfiniteStack" or "ArthurMerlin" just because they are more clever and playful.

Comment: I also find it disappointingly literal, lacking that element of playfulness of some of the others. Although I do agree 'CST' might work well for casual references. But in that case I prefer theorycs.org since "Theoretical Computer Science" is a more common expression than "Computer Science Theory" (Google confirms this ;-))

Comment: Perhaps we should have a "playoff" between the top 2 or 3 names? Might lead to a good discussion.

Comment: Hard to pronounce, at least for non native speakers (unless you cheat and say /see-theory/), and sounds a bit ugly. Looks ugly, come to think of it: the sequence of three capital letteres followed by lowercase … unbalanced. I’m really surprised this got so many votes!

Comment: > I’m really surprised this got so many votes!
"Worse is better" stroke again.

Comment: @Konrad: You can write it all-lowercase: "cstheory.org" doesn't look that bad. Come to think of it, cstheory.org looks almost like a domain name!

Answer (score 30):

## InfiniteStack.org

is a pun on StackOverflow, TM computation, pushdown automata, and concisely conveys the theoretical bent of the site.  The .net and .com variants are also available.

(Acknowledgements to arnab for scratchtape inspiration.)

Answer (score 27):

**TheoryOverflow** seems the right name.  None of the variants com/net/org is taken; I would therefore prefer `theoryoverflow.org` if possible.

`cstheoryoverflow.org` is also still available, but I feel since we are the first ones to use theory (without the cs), this is our chance to keep it out of the hands of the postmodernists.  (This is meant to be a joke, by the way.)

Comment: Problem is that the 'overflow' doesn't make sense. For MO it was a joke based on latex compilation (see the logo).

Comment: I was thinking of a different meaning: TheoryOverflow is the overflow from MathOverflow, when someone says "that's off topic, it's not mathematics".

Comment: he he. Interesting. gets a +1 from me

Comment: General note: With non-.com domains (.org, .net, …) people tend to forget and type .com by default. This is why mathoverflow.com exists and redirects to mathoverflow.net.

Comment: I really prefer when the name is more directed towards the chosen subject (see also #2 in the blog post on choosing a name: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/domain-names/).  A two-word idea from CS Theory that has some relevance would be best.

Comment: I've been reading some discussion on MO about their use of overflow, and apparently it causes them some grief when people confuse StackOverflow and MO in terms of type of audience. That might be a problem for us too.

Comment: There are a fair amount of theory types on SO already though (e.g. three pages of results searching for "coq"), and I would hope that this would also be a place for some of the higher-level discussions there to migrate.

Comment: I think this isn't really informative. Both "theory" and "overflow" do not refer to theoretical computer science. "Theory" you've got everywhere, not just in CS. And "overflow" is a bit used already. I think the name should have something to do with computation (like "CSTheory.org", I suggested).

Comment: I like TheoryOverflow and think it's appropriate that our name reflect the connection to Math/StackOverflow.  Also, TheoryOverflow has become the de facto name on the web (just google "TheoryOverflow" and look at all the references), and I don't think we should try to change a name that has already stuck.

Comment: I'm a fan of TheoryOverflow as well, simply because of its allusion to Math and StackOverflow.  The "Overflow" brand has some meaning of its own by now, and CS insiders know what is meant when you say "I work on theory" -- see, for example, Luca Trevisan's blog "In Theory".

Comment: I also like theoryoverflow because I can abbriviate it to TO. If we choose cstheory, it would be nice to redirect theoryoverflow to it (or vice versa).

Answer (score 20):

## ArthurMerlin.com

Pardon the pun, but since it is a Q and A site, if we are going down the route of CS related names it seems like an obvious candidate. Seems the most appropriate of all interactive proof type things I could think of.

Comment: Outside the USA, TCS includes much more than complexity theory.  AM is pretty much specific to complexity, so I don't much like this one.  It would be good to choose a name that is not likely to put off people from the programming language semantics, concurrency, or logic communities.

Comment: I live in Oxford! I know AM is complexity related, but I thought the fact that it was specifically the question + answer class made it quite appropriate.

Comment: Joe: it's certainly a more interesting name than cstheory!

Comment: .com/.org/.net all available.

Answer (score 13):

## TuringComplete.com

Goal of the site is to be able to represent all topics in TCS. We don't really have branching, but we do have [gotos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness) and the ability to edit memory.

Comment: I like the metaphor, but I am afraid that the name would literally suggest the preference toward recursion theory instead of the stated goal of representing all topics in TCS.

Comment: How about turing.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 11):

## InfiniteTape.org

Available, InfiniteTape.com is taken.

Answer (score 10):

## CSTheory.com

Offered by Kevin McCurley, see [What is a good use for cstheory.com?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/160/what-is-a-good-use-for-cstheory-com)

Answer (score 10):

## TheoryOracle.com

Answer (score 9):

## ChurchTuring.com

Comment: Or CurryHoward.com :-)

Answer (score 8):

## TheoryCS.org

Short and sweet :)

Comment: I prefer CSTheory...

Answer (score 7):

## TCS.SE

(Yes, literally.)

Answer (score 7):

## tcscafe.com

This is based on RJK’s suggestion TheoryCafe.org, but I think that “theory” is pretty vague (it could refer to theoretical physics for example).  My choice of top-level domain is because of a [blog by Robert Cartaino of Stack Overflow](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) where he suggests to prefer .com (but I do not know why .com should be preferred).

It is short, not too straightforward, and not too narrow.  Also, it is recognizable to TCS people without relying on capitalization (hopefully).

Comment: I have posted this name because I think it is better than the other names suggested so far in some way (of course; why would I post a name if I think there is a clearly better name already?)  But honestly speaking, I prefer a more creative and imaginative name if there is a good one.

Comment: Hey Tsuyoshi, nice to bump into you here! Thanks for the improved suggestion. I agree with your comment here that there is still something *missing* in all of the current proposals. We need something with more cheek and wit, but also not narrowing in too much on one particular sub-field or excluding an important one.

Comment: @RJK: Your comment states exactly what I was thinking, and clearer than mine!

Comment: @RJK: And now I learned who you are.  Nice to see you here!

Answer (score 4):

### TheoryCafe.org

is, with apologies to caffeine abstainers, hoping to convey the type of collaborative research discussions that members of our field often have over coffee...
(I realise there is a slight conflict with n-category cafe, but oh well.)

Answer (score 4):

## TheoryFlow

Based on "Max Cut Min Flow", is similar to MO.

.org, .net, .com available.

Answer (score 3):

### AnalyticalEngine.org

is a tongue-in-cheek reference to probably the oldest example of theoretical computer science.  (Hm, Babbage's theory was not converted to practice until well after his death...)  We could also imagine that our research forum is an "engine for analysis" of TCS problems.

(Warning: analyticalengines.com is taken and might spawn some hideous trademark dispute.)

Comment: I like this name.  I was thinking in the same direction (referring to the website itself as a computational device or a model of computation), but I could not come up with a good name.

Answer (score 2):

## TCSoracle.com

(yes it has already been "suggested", but this is at the request of Robert Cartaino, see his comment)

Answer (score 2):

## FiniteOracle.com

Available, as are *.org, *.net.

From [gphilip's infinite stable](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-site-domain-name-be/18#18).

Answer (score 2):

## tcsoverflow.com

More precise than theoryoverflow.com yet still maintains that delightful "overflow" meme but not overly long.

Answer (score 1):

## tcsQandA.org

(not yet taken)

Answer (score 1):

## RecursiveOverflow

.com .org .net available. Named after recursive definitions and recursive functions.

Answer (score 1):

### CompSciTheory.com

I like CSTheory quite a lot, but CS always reminds me of Counterstrike. CompSci just comes across as more user-friendly, and the .com domain is available should we want it.

Answer (score 0):

## http://recursivelyenumerable.org/

Answer (score -1):

## PolymathTheory.com

To promote the idea of collaborative problem solving.

Comment: Gowers' great pun is lost though...

Answer (score -1):

## TheoryInPractice

`.com` and `.org` are registered. `.net` is not. `TheoryInPractice.com`'s asking price is $2588.

Comment: "Theory in Practice" would seem to suggest that this is an applied computer science site... which it is not.

Answer (score -2):

### CSOverflow.com

Seems available (.org as well)

Answer (score -3):

theoreticalcomputerscience.org also seems available

Comment: That seems a little long for a domain name.

Answer (score -3):

## mathunderflow.com

I thought of this a few days ago and forgot to add it. It could be seen as a joke about the status of TCS within the math community.

Comment: OK, perhaps not a FUNNY joke ;-)

Answer (score -8):

### PvsNP.org