# What is a good use for cstheory.com?

Tags: domain

I own the domain cstheory.com.  What do people suggest as good uses for this domain?

**Edit:** from @Robert Cartaino: 
I contacted Kevin to ask him if he was interested in using his **cstheory.com** domain name for this site to complement our top choice: cstheory.org ([link](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-site-domain-name-be/100#100)).

He came to our community to ask what to do with this domain. It was a bit off topic for *that* site so I migrated it here for the community to discuss.

Comment: I've added this domain to the domain name vote thread: http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-site-domain-name-be/163#163

Answer (score 13):

Wait this community to become a full member of the Stack Exchange Network and then donate it to them (Or, at least, permit that they use the domain).

Comment: This is precisely the kind of answer I expected.  I'm not interested in selling the domain - the whole point is to use it for CS theory.  Given the tone of response from this forum, it appears that I need to talk to another community.

Answer (score 0):

Email the SX team, at `team@stackexchange.com`.  If the community are interested in the name (see [What should our site/domain name be?](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-should-our-site-domain-name-be)), the SX team consider this site to be viable, and the SX team are happy about any conditions you might have, then it could be used for the site.

Comment: @Jukka: Done.  Why is it important?